# How to chain flatMap operator on an observable for N times where N is only known at runtime?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm running into a situation where I basically need to do something like below.

```
observableFoo
.flatMap(bar(param[0]))
.flatMap(bar(param[1]))
//...
.flatMap(bar(param[N]))

function bar(param){
  var fn = function(...){
     // return some observable depending on param
  }
  return fn;
}
```

where N is only known at runtime. How can I implement it in a "functional manner" without resorting to an imperative for-loop or some mutable variable?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with a for-loop here? Of course, you can always use recursion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functional way would be to fold over the `param` array (using JavaScript's [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method):

```
param.reduce(function(o, p) {
    return o.flatMap(bar(p)); // probably inline the bar call
}, observableFoo);
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of elegance I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
observableFoo
  .expand(function (x) { 
    return Rx.Observable.just(x).flatMap(bar(param[i++]));
  })
  .take(N)
```

Check the documentation for [expand](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md), and this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/wcdkr220/1/) for an example. The `i` var here is indeed a mutable variable, but one just needs to decide whether it is a problem or if it is harmless.